# Binary CNN Spam Classifier using ResNet50 producing val-train metrices > 0.99 but test metric falls under 0.6. Faulty code or approach?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am working on Binary Spam Classifier project where I have to classify whether an image is spam or not. To get things in detail, let me first show you what are **not spams**:
[image]

[image]

Any image in the world which is not a picture of a question on a paper is a spam be it a bike, black screen or anything.

I used my Custom made dummy model as well as `ResNet50` with and without fine tuning. I have lots of images of questions but I used 47000 images of questions and **COCO 2017 test** data set as spams. Model did well producing great results but when I used it with `imagenet` data set images it performed very poorly. I want to ask if I am doing something wrong here or if not, what should I do to make my model generalised.

```
train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,validation_split=0.20)

train_set = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,target_size=(224,224),
                                               subset='training',class_mode='categorical')

val_set =  train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN,batch_size=128,target_size=(224,224),
                                              subset='validation',class_mode='categorical')


res_net = ResNet50(include_top=False,weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224,224,3),pooling='avg')
fc1 = Dense(1024,activation='relu')(res_net.output)
d1 = Dropout(0.79)(fc1)
out_ = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',name='output_layer')(d1)
model = Model(inputs=res_net.input, outputs= out_)

for layer in res_net.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_set,epochs=3,validation_data=val_set,
                              steps_per_epoch=len(train_set)//BATCH_SIZE,callbacks=callbacks)
```

I  have used `softmax` with `categorical_crossentropy` (2 neurons) and `sigmoid` with `binary_crossentropy` (1 neuron). Model is performing well in all train and validation cases but **Why is it not being generalise**?  Is there one thing wrong with the way I train my model, is the code faulty? Do I need more data, do I train the `resnet` from scratch.

I think I need more data but how much data should I be aiming at so that it tends to **LEARN WHAT A QUESTION IMAGE LOOKS LIKE** because spam could be anything.

Comment: If you use `sigmoid` and `binary_crossentropy` then the `class_mode` should be `'binary'` (instead of `'categorical'`). On the other hand, if you use `softmax` and `categorical_crossentropy`, then the last layer should have 2 units (instead of 1). Have you followed these in your experiments?

Comment: Yes, I have taken of everything. This is just another example from many models that I have tried so far.

Comment: A binary classification problem, are you sure both classes have similar number of samples in training? Also provide some training logs.

Comment: I set the training examples myself. 47K and 42K. Also loss is decreasing and reaches around 0.1  for training and 0.03 for validation with metrics all ? 0.997.

Comment: @Deshwal may be **Supervised Contrastive Learning** helpful. Check [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.11362)

Comment: Is there any chance your model might be too small to be able to generalise properly?

Comment: It's `Resnet50` already. I don't think it's small. or is it?

Comment: you have trained your model on COCO 2017 dataset
as spams, that will produce an 'overfitting" on this data, which you notice when you use imagenet as test , increasing the data will not resolve the poor generalisation. I think the good approach is to use " Image processing to text detection " models.if the model detect some patterns (digits , alphabets ..) the image is not a spam.

Comment: Have you been careful about preprocessing the images? COCO and Imagenet use different data formats I believe one uses images in the BGR format and the other in RGB, they also both use different normalization constants so the data will look completely different to the NN.

Comment: @quizzical_panini Yeah but it should not matter for test data because my **real world data could be in any format and could be of any shape, size, normalized or so.** I think it's even better because it exploited the weak parts of model.

Comment: @TouYou You mean to say I use an OCR? I did not get that part actually. What kind of approach you are suggesting? CNN+LSTM? or something else? Could you please explain a bit  or  provide some link?

Comment: yes, I mean  OCR  , e.g.models that use CNN+RNN+CTC  loss ..https://stackabuse.com/pytesseract-simple-python-optical-character-recognition/

Comment: or you can you built your own model  .https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-handwritten-text-recognition-system-using-tensorflow-2326a3487cd5

Comment: What good that would do? I just want to check if it some spam or not. not recognise digits. Moreover, I get images just made of equations and figures which the OCR model won't be able to detect. An RNN is supposed to extract the features which is the base of OCR too. Why would I burden my model with extra LSTM?